# Tumblr embeded posts return Refused to display 'https://www.tumblr.com/dashboard' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: iframe, tumblr

I have been using tumblr embed in my website for quite some time. However, recently it stopped working. It throws this error:

`Refused to display 'https://www.tumblr.com/dashboard' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'`

Even their own embed endpoint is throwing the same error:
$blogId.tumblr.com/post/$postId/embed

I don't think this is ssl issue. My site is served over ssl and tumblr blog is marked to always serve on ssl.

Any idea how to fix this?

Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit). But happens on opera and vivaldi as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Noticed the exact same thing and it's throwing the same error in Safari. Looks like they've changed their policy of embedding, perhaps since being bought out by Oath this year.

Comment: I filed a ticket to them. First they pushed back and then I filed again, this time they escalated to eng team. Today I realized it's fixed. Embeds are back yay! It's a shame that nobody checked it that long and none of the embeds in the world were not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like fixed after creating multiple tickets from Tumblr help center. No need to do any code change. They fixed their policy for iframing which enables embedding tumblr posts in other domains.

Comment: I'm still having the problem. Did you use their plugin to embed the site, or did you just put your blog in an iFrame? Cheers for pursuing it though.

Comment: Did you make sure that you serve your embed in a site which has https?
Here is my example: https://paylas.io/p/5840ef53b9dcc64776b872fa

Comment: Ah, that might be it, wasn't https!

Answer (score 2):

I just tested a tumblr blog to create an iframe for a site that used to show a tumblr feed, but the page is now blank. Using a free iframe checker, it appears the header states specifically X-Frame-Options: deny. There is also no embed option in the share feature within the blog interface of Tumblr, either, so I'm not sure that Tumblr has resolved this issue just yet.

Comment: Hey Nicole, are you sure that you serve the embed from an https page.

Here is my example iframe from tumblr works fine:
https://paylas.io/p/5840ef53b9dcc64776b872fa